# get() function doesn't yield any result on tuple keys, and the values exist and do match when manually checked

Tags: rust, hashmap

```
let mut FEED_CA_:HashMap<(Address, Address, Address), (iuniswapv2pair_mod::IUniswapV2Pair<Provider<Ws>>, iuniswapv2pair_mod::IUniswapV2Pair<Provider<Ws>>, iuniswapv2pair_mod::IUniswapV2Pair<Provider<Ws>>, iuniswapv2pair_mod::IUniswapV2Pair<Provider<Ws>>, iuniswapv2pair_mod::IUniswapV2Pair<Provider<Ws>>, iuniswapv2pair_mod::IUniswapV2Pair<Provider<Ws>>)> = HashMap::new();
for i in FEED_CA_START{
    let c0 = i[0];
    let c1 = i[1];
    let c2 = i[2];

    let p_01_ = ALL_C.get(&&(*c0, *c1)).ok_or(continue).unwrap();
```

*`FEED_CA_START` is a vec of (c0, c1, c2) tuples :)*

*`ALL_C` is a HashMap of <(Address, Address), Address>* from which I can't get the value out.

The whole iteration fails on last line in the above snippet. There's eight more of those `get()`s, and not one of them gets filled, the output data structure (`FEED_CA_` ) to which I insert results after iterating through the whole db is always `len = 0`.

I've:

- Printed out the values `&(c0, c1)` for each `i` in my tuple `FEED_CA_START`
- Printed out the values of the faulty `&(c0, c1)`, as well as `&(*c0, *c1)` and even `&&(*c0, *c1)`.
- Manually found that they indeed do match, do exist (100% of those calls should succeed).
- Printed out the types of the above and made sure they indeed do match. Same result, even if types of the query and key match and are both exactly: `&(primitive_types::H160, primitive_types::H160)`
- Done some borrow&deref trial-and-error combinations, there's only so many I can try, and still no hope.
- printed out the databases I've derived those from and manually checked - there's multiple matches, and the program returns exactly 0 always, and I've tried multiple functions/methods/iterations, my program always breaks at `get()` function, goes straight to continue.
- I ran a simple test where in a new program I've created a HashMap with addresses akin to `ALL_C` , and accessed it using a tuple key - and there it worked. Here it doesn't. I've even thrown some reference/typing spaghetti there to make sure it breaks as well, it didn't. Got the value every time. Here I'm trying as hard as I can to make it work, and it's day 2 stuck on this issue, dead end.

How do I approach a problem like that? I'm lost.

Comment: Can you extend your problem snippet to a self-contained program that shows the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood the code snippet is correctly, I think your problem is the `.ok_or(continue)`.

> Arguments passed to ok_or are eagerly evaluated; if you are passing the result of a function call, it is recommended to use ok_or_else, which is lazily evaluated.

In other words, the `continue` is always evaluated and so the code is really not doing what you expect.

```rust
        let p_01_ = ALL_C.get(&(c0, c1)).ok_or(continue).unwrap();
        println!("unreachable");
```

As a possible solution, you could use `filter_map` which will ignore all `None` results and then check the length. It doesn't seem very elegant but it might be better that repeated `if let` blocks:

```rust
    // Note: I just guessed some types for an example
    for i in FEED_CA_START {
        let c0 = i.0;
        let c1 = i.1;
        let c2 = i.2;

        let args = vec![(c0, c1), (c0, c2)];
        let ps: Vec<&Address> = args.iter().filter_map(|arg| ALL_C.get(arg)).collect();
        if ps.len() != args.len() {
            continue;
        }

        // Do something
    }
```

Comment: Seems about right, and a case of "have you considered reading the compiler's warnings?" as rustc itself throws up an unreachable code warning (clippy is not even necessary).

Comment: It also seems very odd to convert the `Option` to a `Result` only to immediately unwrap it, it kinda feels like @tommy1213 was looking for `unwrap_or` / `unwrap_or_else`? (probably mistakenly if the goal was to `continue` obviously, that's a job for `if let`, or [`guard!`](https://crates.io/crates/guard))

Comment: @Masklinn I've done unwrap() because I needed the Result type and not Option. I thought it will barely ever return any err, similarly with the continue. I tried to use `if let` originally, but I had a problem with assigning variables to the outcome of a series of `if let` statements, because my 1st block of code was: options and their outcomes; 2nd block of code: operations on those. The compiler obviously said the variables were not found, because they were declared inside if statements. I wasn't able to figure out a clean way, still learning Rust. Thanks for pointers and resources.

Comment: What method should I use to ignore errors in such Option statements, continuing the loop and not crashing the program? I will mark the answer as successful later on,  it seems to be the problem, in my working test I have used something different than continue, I somehow overlooked it when comparing the two.

Comment: @tommy1213 it's not clear why you'd need the `Result` type, you can `unwrap` an `Option` just fine and it'll yield the same thing, or `expect` if you want a custom panic message.

Comment: As to getting values, you can return values out of `if let` (or bind them in `guard` which is shorter) e.g. `let p_01 = if let Some(p_01) = ALL_C.get(...) { p_01 } else { continue };`

Comment: Using the `guard` crate, or the eventual [refutable let feature](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3137-let-else.html), is the somewhat simpler (and less redundant) `guard!(let Some(p_01) = ALL_C.get(...) else { continue });` (refutable let is the same without the `guard!` part, but requires nightly and enabling the `let_else` feature as it's not stable yet).

Comment: @tommy1213 there are a few different options for how to structure the code differently. If you can add a few more details about what you would then use `p_01_` for I could see what would work? With 8 other `get`'s like your question states I would probably split out the handling into a function that returns a `Result<()>` and then in that function use `let p1 = ALL_C.get(&(c0, c1))?; // let p2 = etc`

Comment: only if all of the options return` Some` in block 1, execute the second block of code (working with the reads from block 1) is what I try to do. This part of the program is simple, it reads data from one db, and then transforms the data a bit (by instantiating a new object using the return from the read) assigning to the new db. I've tried  `continue` mainly because I expect 99% of those reads to succeed and I thought it would save on lines, I also misunderstood a lot unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

As per the other answer, `continue` is evaluated so it never get to check the other code. IMO it should be imposible to construct that in the first place.

On the other hand, it is not a good construct to do that, you should use something more rusty like:

```rust
let mut FEED_CA_:HashMap<(Address, Address, Address), (iuniswapv2pair_mod::IUniswapV2Pair<Provider<Ws>>, iuniswapv2pair_mod::IUniswapV2Pair<Provider<Ws>>, iuniswapv2pair_mod::IUniswapV2Pair<Provider<Ws>>, iuniswapv2pair_mod::IUniswapV2Pair<Provider<Ws>>, iuniswapv2pair_mod::IUniswapV2Pair<Provider<Ws>>, iuniswapv2pair_mod::IUniswapV2Pair<Provider<Ws>>)> = HashMap::new();
for i in FEED_CA_START{
    let c0 = i[0];
    let c1 = i[1];
    let c2 = i[2];

    if let Some(p_01_) = ALL_C.get(&&(*c0, *c1)) {
       // compute stuff over `p_01_`
    } else { // else could be avoided if you don't need to compute anything else in the loop if there is nothing for the key
        continue
    };
    ...
```